# What type of magic is LinkedIn doing with their JS SDK? script body and src are present, plus body in weird format

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

I want to integrate LinkedIn sharing on my page.

Reading the documentation that LinkedIn provides here: 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk

.. I was surprised to see they require this script tag in the head secion of my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [API_KEY]
    onLoad:    [ONLOAD]
    authorize: [AUTHORIZE]
    lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
</script>
```

I don't get what is happening here. First of all, w3schools says that """Note: If the "src" attribute is present, the  element must be empty.""" (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp).
I also went here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element
(I'm not 100% sure how authoritative this is...but looks authoritative based on the format and length :P) - it also says there that if there's a `src` attribute, then the body should *basically* be empty - in any case - LinkedIn's script syntax is not explainable by these 2 resources.

So does anyone know what's up with the script body syntax? Are those JS labels? And if so, I don't get how they're used. I thought labels are used with continue/break statements, to get out of loops. I don't understand how LinkedIn's API can get information from me if I provide it in that syntax.
Is the script body somehow fed to the script, and it parses it itself?

Can someone please explain to me what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said is correct. When the `src` attribute is added, the body of the `script` is not executed. There is a way to get around this however. That's by retrieving the script tag, extracting the `innerHTML` and using `eval` on it. You will need to of course do that on document ready.

I don't know how LinkedIn does it exactly, but HTML standards didn't change for them nor the order of loading, so either they use something similar to what I explained or some more clever way of parsing the body of the script.

Other notes to consider: instead of using document ready event, you could bind that into your library. As in retrieve the last available script tag, and extract the body, at the time of load of your library, that will be the last element loaded either way, so you should be able to retrieve the code without using any events. (That would need testing, but DOM elements are loaded synchronously, top-down approach).

Obviously using `eval` is not recommended, its quite slow, but definitely provides the functionality you're looking for.

PS. Forgive any formatting errors. I'm typing this from my mobile, 2k miles away from home. Otherwise I'd be more than happy to even provide some sample code snippets and do the above testing myself.